# Set a column value as key in JSON output

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Suppose I have this SQL working:

```
SELECT(
    SELECT 
        a.id,
        a.label,
        a.text
    FROM [data] a 
    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
) AS 'data'
```

which will produce JSON with this structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": "N/A",
        "label": "test",
        "text": "Not applicable"
    },
    {
        "id": "ID",
        "label": "test2",
        "text": "Identification"
    }
]
```

What I would like to have is this structure - the value of the label column used as key.

```
[{
    "test": {
        "id": "N/A",
        "text": "Not applicable"
    },
    "test2": {
        "id": "ID",
        "text": "Identification"
    }
}]
```

Is it possible, with SQL (not building the JSON by strings)?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: It's SQL Server 2016

Comment: Don't think you can do it before SQL Server 2022 where json_object is introduced, but you can solve it by some string manipulations

Comment: @siggemannen Thanks for the comment. I was hoping to accomplish it without string manipulations.

Comment: As A. Pope wrote, hope springs eternal. Although to be fair, it was written before the advent of relational databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not yet support `JSON_OBJECT_AGG`, which would have worked well for this.

You can instead use `STRING_AGG` and `STRING_ESCAPE`, with a nested `FOR JSON` subquery.

**This works for SQL Server 2017+.**

```sql
SELECT
  data = '[{' +
    STRING_AGG(
      '"' + STRING_ESCAPE(a.label, 'json') + '":' + j.json,
      ','
    ) + '}]'
FROM [data] a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      a.id,
      a.text
    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) j(json);
```

Comment: `STRING_AGG` was added in SQL Server 2017, so it's not available in 2016.

Comment: I accepted your answer. I saw this was possible (by string construction) and I hoped to avoid it. Not possible in version 2016 seems to be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use FOR XML to concatenate/aggregate the FOR JSON PATH of id and text

```
SELECT N'[{'+STUFF((
SELECT N',"'+STRING_ESCAPE(D.label,'json')+N'":',(SELECT D.id,D.text FOR JSON PATH,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
FROM data D FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,N'')+N'}]'
```